# check is Process is Alive from PID while handling recycled PID

Tags: process, ipc

From what I seen online you call kill method in c++ in order to see if the process is alive. the issue with that is PID's get rycled and the same PID your looking for may not be the same process. I have a program that has two processes that are not children of each other. The only way to communicate with them is IPC. I would like my host process to shutdown when the client process shuts down. In order to do that I have to know when the client's process is no longer alive.

In Windows, they have what's called a process handler that will reserve the PID from getting recycled until the process that created the handle is closed. I am wondering how to achieve this for macOS/Linux (POSIX) systems.

The problematic code as PID's are reycled.

```
if (0 == kill(pid, 0))
{
    // Process exists.
}
```

Comment: Linux-only: https://lwn.net/Articles/794707/

Comment: I'm not a programmer, so the other advice is probably better, but I latched onto this statement: *"The only way to communicate with them is IPC"*. Would it be reasonable to set up some kind of heartbeat protocol between the two endpoints? When the other side stops heartbeating, you know you've lost that process.

Comment: @JeffSchaller issue is solved already. IPC heartbeat would DC occasionally and return false positives I don't want this. This is why we check for PIDisAlive. I fixed it in my answer below using the process start time along with the PID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to either **reserve the PID** on windows by *cacheing* and not closing the `process handle`. For `POSIX` Systems we simply get the process's start time from the **kernal** `OS DEPENDANT!` and then check if the cached start time equals the current start time. If it doesn't a PID conflict is detected and it returns false.

Windows:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

map<DWORD, HANDLE> handles;
bool isProcessAlive(DWORD pid)
{
    HANDLE process;
    if(handles.find(pid) == handles.end())
    {
        process = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, FALSE, pid);
        handles[pid] = process;
    }
    else
    {
        process = handles[pid];
    }
    DWORD ret = WaitForSingleObject(process, 0);
    bool isRunning = ret == WAIT_TIMEOUT;
    if(!isRunning)//close the cached handle to free the PID and erase from the cache
    {
        CloseHandle(process);
        handles.erase(pid);
    }
    return isRunning;
}
```

MacOS:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/_types/_timeval.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <sys/proc.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
/**
 * map of unsigned long, creation time either in jiffies, ms, or in clock ticks or different on mac even. so we keep it as a string
 */
std::map<unsigned long, string> handles;
/**
 * returns true if the process is alive and attempts to suggest a handle to linux's os that we are reading the directory /proc/[PID] reserve this PID till program shutdown
 */
bool isProcessAlive(unsigned long pid)
{
    // Get process info from kernel
    struct kinfo_proc info;
    int mib[] = { CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_PID, (int)pid };
    size_t len = sizeof info;
    memset(&info,0,len);
    int rc = sysctl(mib, (sizeof(mib)/sizeof(int)), &info, &len, NULL, 0);

    //exit program sysctl failed to verify PID
    if (rc != 0)
    {
        handles.erase(pid);
        return false;
    }

    //extract start time and confirm PID start time equals org start time
    struct timeval tv = info.kp_proc.p_starttime;
    if(tv.tv_sec == 0)
    {
        handles.erase(pid);
        return false;
    }
    string time = to_string(tv.tv_usec) + "-" + to_string(tv.tv_sec);
    if(handles.find(pid) != handles.end())
    {
        string org_time = handles[pid];
        if(org_time != time)
        {
            cout << "PID Conflict PID:" << pid << " org_time:" + org_time << " new_time:" << time << endl;
            handles.erase(pid);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        handles[pid] = time;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Linux:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <signal.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fstream>

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#include <cerrno>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/param.h"

/**
 * map of unsigned long, creation time either in jiffies, ms, or in clock ticks or different on mac even. so we keep it as a string
 */
std::map<unsigned long, string> handles = {};
/**
 * returns true if the process is alive and attempts to suggest a handle to linux's os that we are reading the directory /proc/[PID] reserve this PID till program shutdown
 */
bool isProcessAlive(unsigned long pid)
{
    ifstream procFile;
    string f = "/proc/"+ std::to_string(pid)+ "/stat";
    procFile.open(f.c_str());
    if(!procFile.fail())
    {
        //get creation time of current pid's process
        char str[255];
        procFile.getline(str, 255);  // delim defaults to '\n'

        vector<string> tmp;
        istringstream iss(str);
        copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
             istream_iterator<string>(),
             back_inserter<vector<string> >(tmp));

        string creation_time = tmp.at(21);

        //check if the process's creation time matches the cached creation time
        if(handles.find(pid) != handles.end())
        {
            string org = handles[pid];
            //if the pid's creation time is not the cached creation time we assume it's not the same process and the original has closed
            //unlike java the ==,!= actually checks .equals() when comparing
            if(creation_time != org)
            {
                std::cerr << "PID conflict:" + to_string(pid) + " orgCreationTime:" + org + " newCreationTime:" + creation_time;
                handles.erase(pid);
                procFile.close();
                return false;
            }
        }
        handles[pid] = creation_time;
        procFile.close();
        return true;
    }
    handles.erase(pid);
    procFile.close();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This leads to race conditions. Hence the pidfd approach A.B. linked to in their comment beneath your post: https://lwn.net/Articles/794707/

Answer (score 0):

> From what I seen online you call kill method in c++ in order to see if the process is alive. the issue with that is PID's get rycled and the same PID your looking for may not be the same process

Exactly, so that `kill` approach does **not** work. Really, end of story there. It's not a working tool for this.

Two options:

- if the process you're watching is your child process (or in your own process' process group), `waitpid` is meant exactly for watching when it exits
- if the process is *not* your child process, POSIX "ideals" kind of suggest your own process has no business interacting tightly with that process' lifetime (at least that's my takeawy from `waitpid`'s limitations). You can hope that you have "tracing" privileges and use `ptrace` to attach to the other process and wait for `exit` calls.

Comment: this isn't an answer. I specifically stated that it's not a child process. this is because a server has no business spawning a client and it communicates via IPC. I would like to how to check if the client is alive from server. and if the server is alive from client

Comment: I address exactly that case in the second bullet point?!

Comment: ptrace causes more issues then it solves. It requires your process to handle tracing and I wanted a generic is process alive without that crap. It also pauses the client and there isn't a way to stop that once the trace has been setup. I need a way to reserve the PID while my PID checker is running

Comment: Don't know why you are so negative. I explain why there's no simple solution, and oder you a workable alternative.

Comment: there actually was a huge easy fix for this don't know why everyone is stating there is no solution. the solution is to check the process's creation time when checking if PID isAlive on top of checking if it was alive. this will now prevent PID conflicts from returning true instead of false

Comment: That opens up room for a race condition

Comment: the process that spawns the program will cache the PID time there is no room for error unless the PC is running for like 60 years then it may get a false true if and only if the same MS and PID are exactly the same and even then chances are low.

Comment: Well why take the root of no guarantees that is on top pretty complicated if there's a definitely correct way?